# Sequentially read a specific record in a file then display it

Tags: cobol

```
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT MASTER-FILE ASSIGN TO "MASTER-PRODUCT-FILE.DAT"
       ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL
       ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL.

       SELECT TRANSACTION-FILE ASSIGN TO "INVENTORY-FILE.DAT"
       ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

DATA DIVISION.
  *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
   FILE SECTION.
   FD MASTER-FILE.
   01 MASTER-RECORDS.
       05 PR-CODE                  PIC 9(7).
       05 PR-NAME                  PIC X(30).
       05 PR-PRICE                 PIC 9(5)V99.
       05 PR-QUANTITY              PIC S9(6).

   FD TRANSACTION-FILE.
   01 TRANSACTION-RECORDS.
       05 TR-CODE                  PIC 9(6).
       05 TR-DATE.
           10 DATE-YEAR            PIC 9(4).
           10 DATE-MONTH           PIC 99.
           10 DATE-DAY             PIC 99.
       05 TR-PRODCODE              PIC 9(7).
       05 TR-PRODNAME              PIC X(30).
       05 TR-PRODPRICE             PIC 9(5).
       05 TR-PRODQUANTITY          PIC S9(6).
       05 TR-PRODSALES             PIC 9(6)V99.

 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  *Current Date
   01 CDate.
       05 CYear                    PIC 9(4).
       05 CMonth                   PIC 99.
       05 CDay                     PIC 99.
  *Current Time
   01 CTime.
       05 CHour                    PIC 99.
       05 CMinute                  PIC 99.
*End of File
   01 EOF                          PIC A(1).
  *Input Product Code
   01 WS-PR-CODE                   PIC 9(7).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
  *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
   0000-MAIN.
       PERFORM 1000-INCREMENT.
       PERFORM 2000-INTRO.
       PERFORM 3000-DATA-ENTRY-PR-CODE.
       PERFORM 4000-OPEN-FILE.
       PERFORM 5000-READ-MASTER-FILE.
       PERFORM 6000-CLOSE-FILE.
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
   1000-INCREMENT.
  *Increment the transaction code to 1
       MOVE 000000 TO TR-CODE
       ADD 1 TO TR-CODE.
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
   2000-INTRO.
  *Current date and time validation
       ACCEPT  CDate FROM DATE YYYYMMDD.
       ACCEPT  CTime FROM TIME.
  *System's header
       DISPLAY SPACES.
       DISPLAY "--------------------------------------------------".
       DISPLAY "|                  INVENTORY SYSTEM              |".
       DISPLAY "--------------------------------------------------".
       DISPLAY SPACES.
       DISPLAY "         TRANSACTION NUMBER : "TR-CODE
       DISPLAY "         TRANSACTION DATE   : "CMonth"/"CDay"/"CYear
       DISPLAY "         TRANSACTION TIME   : "CHour":"CMinute
       DISPLAY SPACES.
       DISPLAY "      **** PLEASE ENTER PRODUCT DETAILS ****      ".
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
   3000-DATA-ENTRY-PR-CODE.
       DISPLAY "PRODUCT CODE    : " WITH NO ADVANCING.
       ACCEPT WS-PR-CODE.

       PERFORM 5000-READ-MASTER-FILE.
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
   4000-OPEN-FILE.
       OPEN I-O MASTER-FILE
       OPEN OUTPUT TRANSACTION-FILE.
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------
   5000-READ-MASTER-FILE.
       PERFORM UNTIL EOF = "Y"
           READ MASTER-FILE INTO WS-PR-CODE
               AT END MOVE "Y" TO EOF
               NOT AT END DISPLAY MASTER-RECORDS
           END-READ
       END-PERFORM.
  *-----------------------------------------------------------------     
   6000-CLOSE-FILE.
       CLOSE MASTER-FILE.
       CLOSE TRANSACTION-FILE.
       STOP RUN.
```

How can I fix this? My problem is that when I enter the product code, it doesn't display the product details. The error is READ/START not allowed. Can you teach me how to find a specific record in a file? At first I manually created the .DAT file, inserted few records according to the data types and format. Please see the .DAT file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-JYlsx2A-2qSDNmSHZvLVA4dTA/view?usp=sharing).

Here is the sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bruce Martin is correct. The only sensible way to do this, where you have to display information after each input, is with an indexed file.

However, it may be an exercise you have to complete using a sequential file.

First, you need a single process to drive your program, which in this case is the user-input. This should be the main loop of the program.

For each user-input except the terminal one, you OPEN the file, loop through reading the file until end-of-file, and in that loop *test the data entered by the user* against the *data on the master-file*, producing the output when there is a match. The `IF` statement is probably what you will use for that.

If that gets your through the assignment, then forget about this "technique" entirely, other than to remember "I mustn't do it that way again. Design first, program after."

Some tips: look at how to use, and use, FILE STATUS; code with the minimum number of full-stops/periods in the PROCEDURE DIVISION; if using numbers to prefix paragraph-names, don't put them on until the program is tested, it'll save you either renumbering or leaving them in a useless tangle; understand 88-leven condition names, and use them; I've never seen a `PIC A` in a real program, its benefit is minimal and lack of knowledge of it will cause confusion; don't do more than necessary, but don't do less either.

An example of that last is this:

```
   MOVE 000000 TO TR-CODE
   ADD 1 TO TR-CODE.
```

A 0, or a figurative-constant ZERO (or ZEROS or ZEROES), does not have to be given a length. The compiler sorts it out.

```
   MOVE ZERO                           TO TR-CODE
   ADD 1                               TO TR-CODE
   .
```

That's the same. But this is better:

```
   MOVE 1                              TO TR-CODE
   .
```

Easier to understand (no-one will ever ask, "why do they MOVE ZERO then ADD 1?"), easier to code, maintain and less stress on the CPU.

Comment: I would try this one. Thanks for the suggestions. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at your flow control.  First this section:

```
   PERFORM 3000-DATA-ENTRY-PR-CODE.
   PERFORM 4000-OPEN-FILE.
   PERFORM 5000-READ-MASTER-FILE.
```

I assume by

you mean that you were executing `3000-DATA-ENTRY-PR-CODE` when you got the error, which reads

```
3000-DATA-ENTRY-PR-CODE.
   DISPLAY "PRODUCT CODE    : " WITH NO ADVANCING.
   ACCEPT WS-PR-CODE.

   PERFORM 5000-READ-MASTER-FILE.
```

Note that you jump directly to `5000-READ-MASTER-FILE` without ever having executed `4000-OPEN-FILE`, which opens the file.

Rather than jump to `PERFORM 5000-READ-MASTER-FILE.`, I would return from that section and allow your main flow control to first open and then read the master file.

Comment: Eric J. It fixed the reading of the of the file, but it displays all of the records. How can read and display a SPECIFIC record based from the user's product code entered?

Comment: Not sure... it's been 20+ years since I programmed in COBOL.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you should be using is a **Indexed sequential** file. Using a sequential file, your options would be
* to load the file into and array then rewrite it at the end
* Copy to an index file then copy it back
* open and close the file for each update (and rewrite each record).

**none** of the above options should **ever** be used !!!

An indexed file would be defined something like (taken from [Index file processing](http://theamericanprogrammer.com/programming/17-vsamrnd1.shtml):

`001600     SELECT VSAM-KSDS-FILE ASSIGN VSAMKSDS
001700        ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
001800*    NOTICE THE RANDOM NEXT
001900        ACCESS MODE IS RANDOM
002000        RECORD KEY IS VSAM-KSDS-RECORD-KEY
000600        FILE STATUS  IS VSAM-STATUS-CODE
000700                        VSAM-EXTENDED-STATUS-CODE.`

and to read

             `Move key           to File-record-key
             READ File
                 INVALID KEY DISPLAY "Read Error :-", FileStatus
             END-READ`

This [site](http://www.csis.ul.ie/cobol/examples/#Direct) has a few index sequential examples, also [google it](http://index%20sequential%20cobol%20example)